# Rails select is not giving the correct record while executing SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` in select using the below `ActiveRecord` query, but it is not giving the correct result.

```
1. 
Job.where(id: [1,2])
  .group(:user_level)
  .select("user_level, SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_datetime, end_datetime) - unpaid_break_time) / 60 * hourly_rate) AS income")

2.
Job.select("user_level, SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_datetime, end_datetime) -  unpaid_break_time) / 60 * hourly_rate) as income")
               .where(id: [1,2]).group(:user_level)

3.
Job.find_by_sql("
  SELECT user_level, SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_datetime,end_datetime) -  unpaid_break_time)/60 * hourly_rate) as income
  FROM jobs
  WHERE id IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY user_level
")
```

All three are giving same result i.e. `[#<Job id: nil, user_level: 0.33e1>]`

Expected:  `[{user_level: 0.33e1, income: 34}]`

If I execute the SQL generated from above 3 in `Workbench` , I got the correct result. So, query is correct.

Also, If I use, `pluck` instead of `select`, I got the correct result but in Array as `pluck` returns array.

```
Job.where(id: [1,2]).group(:user_level)
   .pluck("user_level, sum(((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_datetime,end_datetime) -  unpaid_break_time)/60 * hourly_rate)) as income")
```

So, how to use `Select` to get the expected output?

Note: In above query, id: 1,2 are just for example, the actual ids are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try calling `.income` on the job (`#<Job id: nil, user_level: 0.33e1>`)?

Rails takes all the returned columns and assigns them to the record, but only displays attributes that the model actually has in the default `.inspect` that the console shows.

Calling `.attributes` on the job should also give you the income in a hash.